# is it possible change user-agent for a single window?

Tags: node-webkit

I open a second window like that... its possible change the user-agent or other values for this window??

```
var new_win = gui.Window.open('http://google.com', {
    position: 'center',
    width: 300,
    height: 300 
    //,show: false 
});
```

I need change randomly this params(headers) for that my application works fine.

im using:

```
node-webkit v0.11.4
node.js v0.11.13-pre
Chromium 38.0.2125.104
commit hash: fa7a807-d8ecacd-e98a5c7-f2f89e2-d9a9d39-cdd879e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find any solution to change the user-agent in `Window.open`.

But you can use [iframe#nwUserAgent](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Changes-to-dom#nwUserAgent) to change it .

For example:

`index.html`

```
var new_win = gui.Window.open('iframe.html', {
    position: 'center',
    width: 300,
    height: 300 
    //,show: false 
});
```

`iframe.html`

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" nwUserAgent="test" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Yeah... But the problem is that in the server side can see that i access this page by iframe

Comment: You can add `nwfaketop` and `nwdisable`  in `iframe`, see the detail with this link :https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Mini-browser-in-iframe